# Cookie path in Javascript for all page (darkmode)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In PHP, depending on the cookie `darkmode` use a CSS pair or other.

```
<?php if (isset($_COOKIE["darkmode"]) && $_COOKIE["darkmode"] == "1") {?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style-dark.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/header-dark.css" />
<?php } else {?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/header.css" />
<?php }?>
```

It's works. I'm developing -in Javascript- a button that, when click it, change the dark mode. It's works fine in the main page, but in other subdirectories not work.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle dark mode</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    let name = "darkmode=";
    let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        let c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            if (c.substring(name.length, c.length) == 0) {
                document.cookie = "darkmode=1;path='/'";
            } else {
                document.cookie = "darkmode=0;path='/'";
            }
        }
    }
    window.location.reload();
}
```

What is the correct way to indicate that the cookie affects the entire system? I understand that `path="/"` is enough. I have test `path="/*"`, `path="*"`

Comment: _"I understand that `path="/"` is enough"_ - yes, should be. Should not need the quotes, but they should not be a problem either (MDN mentions something regarding those with really old browser versions, but that should not apply any more.) Can you delete _all_ cookies for the site, and try again? If you have "old" cookies that might have been set for more specific paths (deliberately, or by accident), there might be some sort of overlap now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was ok. The problem was in the cookie tested, once the cookies was deleted, the problem deleted too.